# Rotating a font awesome icon on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to rotate the font awesome refresh icon on hover.

This is the normal version:
`<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>`

And here's the spinning version:
 `<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>`

I want to rotate the icon only on hover.

Here's the failed: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw7LH/174/)

```css
.fa-spin-hover:hover {
   -webkit-animation: spin 2s;
   -moz-animation: spin 2s;
   -o-animation: spin 2s;
   animation: spin 2s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin-hover"></i>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the `fa-spin` keyframe.

CSS:

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover {
    animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}
// The animation bellow is taken from font-awesome.css
@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(359deg);transform:rotate(359deg)}}
@keyframes fa-spin{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{-webkit-transfo rm:rotate(359deg);transform:rotate(359deg)}}
```

HTML

```
 <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin-hover"></i>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uevfyghr/1/

Comment: ok. how can i make it rotate when hovered without interruptions (even if the user moves away his mouse it should finish rotating)

Comment: @Zack It will be a bit tricky to do this without JavaScript, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/95qrk3jq/

Comment: its different from before, once hovered it should complete its spin, even if i move away my mouse from it.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/bcqc8qzs/1/ Done that in a hurry so feel free to make it better.

Answer (score 14):

Use following `CSS`. Hope this will help you.

```css
.fa.fa-refresh:hover {  
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.fa.fa-refresh {
     transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin-hover"></i>
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/Xw7LH/177/

**Update:**

Hope this will fulfill your need.

```css
.fa.fa-refresh:hover {  
    -webkit-animation: infinite-spinning 1s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
    animation: infinite-spinning 1s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

@keyframes infinite-spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin-hover"></i>
```

Comment: can you make it rotate a bit faster and stop at its original position once.

Comment: See updated `CSS` propety of `.fa.fa-refresh:hover` @Zack

Answer (score 3):

You can simply disable the animation when *not* on hover.

```css
.fa-spin-hover:not(:hover) {
   animation: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin fa-spin-hover"></i>
```

Comment: this is not what i asked.

Comment: Please don't do this since it breaks the font-awesome's `.fa-spin` default behavior. Your collaborators will never know why their spinner is not spinning if you do this in your css code.

Comment: @Zack what did you ask then?

Comment: only spin on hover, not the reverse

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the animation of CSS3, you need to define the animation keyframes that correspond to the starting and ending positions (rotations) of the animation.  You can read more at [Mozilla's Developer Handbook](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations).

In this case, you want the starting keyframe to be at 0 degrees (in CSS as `0deg`, or more generally, at `ndeg` where `n` is a rotation in degrees) and the ending keyframe to be at whatever many degrees you want (e.g. `360deg` for 1x revolution clockwise, `720deg` for 2x revolutions clockwise, etc.).

In code, this translates to

```css
.fa-spin-hover:hover {
   -webkit-animation: spin 2s;
   -moz-animation: spin 2s;
   -o-animation: spin 2s;
   animation: spin 2s;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin-hover"></i>
```

Comment: ok. how can i make it rotate when hovered without interruptions (even if the user moves away his mouse it should finish rotating)